# Can the runtime of code (due to array size) be so long it stops the code from starting all together?

Tags: python, arrays, jupyter-notebook, runtime, jupyter-lab

I'm using python in Jupyterlab.

I'm trying to simply take an array with 700000 coordinate points and collect and average them into 100nm squares.

I know the code works fine, as it worked with a 5000 array.

When I try with the larger array, it seems the IDE times out before the code is fully executed.
Or can anyone see a infinite loop in my code to stop it from ever completing?

First half of working code:

```
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

xtot = 10.0
ytot = 20.0
xstep = 0.1
ystep = 0.1
x = 0.0
y = 0.0

T = np.array([])
Tygrad = np.array([])

#Convert .txt to .csv

read_file = pd.read_csv (r'/Users/rjordan/Documents/PHD PROJECT/comsol/April 2021 simulations/OOMMF Para to Perp 1 to 4.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
read_file.to_csv (r'/Users/rjordan/Documents/PHD PROJECT/comsol/April 2021 simulations/OOMMF Para to Perp 1 to 4.csv', index=None)

​#read in data file and assign to DataFrame
col_list = ["X", "Y", "Z", "Color"]

df = pd.read_csv("/Users/rjordan/Documents/PHD PROJECT/comsol/April 2021 simulations/OOMMF Para to Perp 1 to 4.csv", usecols=col_list)

n = df.shape[0]
XM = max(df["X"])
YM = max(df["Y"])
TM = max(df["Color"])

print(XM)
print(YM)
print(TM)
print(n)
print()

10.000000000000002
20.000000000000004
393.02205716505614
713457
```

Second half of code that never actually will spit out anything (my estimate from the 5000 array is that it should take 7 hours to complete):

```
while x < xtot:
    x += xstep
    y = 0.0 
    while y < ytot:
        Tot = 0.0
        N = 0.0
        y += ystep
        for i in range(n):
            if df["X"][i] <= x and df["X"][i] >= (x-xstep) and df["Y"][i] <= y and df["Y"][i] >= (y-ystep):
                Tot += df["Color"][i]
                N += 1 
        Tsq = Tot/N
        T = np.append(T, Tsq)
Tx = int(xtot/xstep)
Ty = int(ytot/ystep)
To = T.reshape(Tx,Ty)               
Tn = T.shape
Ton = To.shape
Tm = max(T)
print(Tm)
print(Tn)
print(Ton)
print(T)
print(To)
```

Comment: Why, why, why?!?! are you doing this nested like this? You have to do `xtot * ytot * n` operations. Please, change this to: 1. prepare your `xtot * ytot` output (or maybe even just one `xtot` long list looking at the code). and then do a single iteration over `df` and calculate which data to update (sth like `floor(df["X"][i] / xstep)`). Moving from `xtot * ytot * n` to `xtot * ytot + n` will be a huge improvement.

Comment: @Faboor I mean, the operation is literally just 1 division, I didn't think it'd make that much of a difference. but sure, so you're saying if essentially keep the same code but add up all the different N's into an array then I can divide the whole array of T by N in one big swoop?

Comment: oh wait i see what you mean now